# Is there a Test Case Automation Manager that can send HTTP Post requests?

Tags: http-post, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcase, continuous-testing

I have the requirement of executing automated test scripts not only during continuous testing, but also by demand through a UI. This is what I have:

- automated test scripts in different languages (ruby and JS).
- an API that executes these scripts.
- a very poor custom made UI that communicates with the API.

I need a test cases manager that can send HTTP Post requests to any made in-house API. However, I haven't been able to find one. When I look for a tool, I need to get into the documentation and test it in order to find out their capabilities. So far, HipTest was promising but it only accepts HTTP Post and Get Requests, as it cannot send anything from the UI if its not integrated with Jenkins. I'm about to test some Jira plugins, but this will take time and it might not have what I need (I don't know yet, I have to test it fully). Since this whole investigation will take time, I'd like to know if someone out there had the need of a test case manager that sends HTTP post requests to any API or if you think is better that I do it myself (so I can use reporting tools only like Allure). As for other capabilities, like reporting or updating tests with HTTP requests, most of the tools out there have that and are very complete on that aspect so I don't care about that at the moment.

Comment: Hi Morgan, I'm Vincent from Hiptest dev team. So far indeed we do not have any hooks that can ping an external tool via a GET or POST request. I'll add that to our product backlog for the next discussions.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks!

Comment: @Morgan Soren have you take a look at [soapUI](https://www.soapui.org/)

Comment: @user1207289 thats a rest and soap testing tool. I'm looking for a test case manager.